Python use ipwhois to loop over a list of ip addresses and grab 'name'
I have a looong list of IP addresses I need to loop over and check the 'name' or 'owner'.
The following python gives me a 'results' dict
from ipwhois import IPWhois
from pprint import pprint
obj = IPWhois('74.125.225.229')
results = obj.lookup_rdap()

Inside the results dictionary I have this with 'name' several dictionaries in, the 'GOGL' key is different every time -
'objects': {'GOGL': {'contact': {'address': [{'type': None,
                                               'value': '1600 Amphitheatre '
                                                        'Parkway\n'
                                                        'Mountain View\n'
                                                        'CA\n'
                                                        '94043\n'
                                                        'United States'}],
                                  'email': None,
                                  'kind': 'org',
                                  'name': 'Google LLC',

This (bad)python gets me there...
objects_dict = results.get('objects', {})  # Get the list of objects
gogl_dict = objects_dict.get('GOGL', {})  # Get the 'contacts' dictionary
contact_dict = gogl_dict.get('contact', {})  # Get the 'contacts' dictionary
name = contact_dict.get('name') 
print(f"Name: {name}")

But the path is never the same, for a Microsoft IP it would be like this

'objects': {'MSFT': {'contact': {'address': [{'type': None,
                                               'value': 'One Microsoft Way\n'
                                                        'Redmond\n'
                                                        'WA\n'
                                                        '98052\n'
                                                        'United States'}],
                                  'email': None,
                                  'kind': 'org',
                                  'name': 'Microsoft Corporation',

My question is how can I loop over a list of IP addresses and pull the value under the 'name' key when the key directly under 'objects' is always different?

Is there only one key inside 'objects'?

The key directly under "objects" might differ. But is there always only one key? If so, you could just get the first key out of that dictionary with objects_dict[list(objects_dict.keys())[0]]

I did some experiments and found that there could be more than one item inside the 'objects' dict.
See the code below for a way of extracting all the name entries given an ip address:
from ipwhois import IPWhois

def get_whois_name(ip):
    obj = IPWhois(ip)
    results = obj.lookup_rdap()
    objects = results['objects']
    names = [(key,objects[key]['contact']['name']) for key in objects.keys()]
    return names


ips = ['74.125.225.229','20.112.250.133','17.253.144.10']
for ip in ips:
    print(ip, get_whois_name(ip))

Example Output:
74.125.225.229 [('GOGL', 'Google LLC')]
20.112.250.133 [('MSFT', 'Microsoft Corporation')]
17.253.144.10 [('APPLEC-1-Z', 'Apple Inc.'), ('ZA42-ARIN', 'Apple Computer Inc'), ('RAUSC15-ARIN', 'David Rauschenberg')]


Wow, bigtime, thank you!!  At this point I'm not sure I'll EVER get grabbing information from nested dictionaries or json.
